# prevent specific asp.net page from being logged out

Tags: asp.net, iis, logout

I have a specific page within a webform application which i never want to log out.

It is not within a masterpage
It has an auto refresh tag in the header to refresh the entire page on intervals:

(added via code)

all functions correctly but appears to logout after 2 hours.

Comment: Why do you want a page to keep reloading over and over?  What exactly are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: good question! its a dashboard styled page which needs to reload to present a different iframe contents (which is a html generated report on a schedule)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could fix the issue by configuring your web.config for an individual location, like below:

> ```
>  <location path="PATH TO THE FOLDER/FILE THAT YOU DO NOT WANT TO BE AUTHORIZED">
>       <system.web>
>            <authorization>
>                 <allow users="*" />
>            </authorization>
>       </system.web>
>  </location>
> ```

Comment: I think this seems to be working with a few breaks here and there.  I'm refreshing the page with <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5"> (parameterised and added via the page load routine).  I think look for some session variables or reload them if not present.  is there a better way to have a single page in an asp.net application auto refresh to reload content and not log out?